# Using $match plus aggregate won't give me a correct average ($avg)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and my model is called Db.Property.

When i do Db.Property.find() and i pass the object below **i get the expected results**.

```
{ 
    address: { "$in": [ /f/i ] },
    environments: 1,
    price: { "$gt": 3000, "$lt": 20000 },
    timestamp: { 
        "$gt": 2017-01-23T22:38:24.904Z,
        "$lt": 2017-03-24T22:38:24.906Z 
    },
    _id: { "$nin": [ "58be3e36309524218ca5eb2e" ] } 
}
```

**Please notice i'm adding a "$nin" which excludes an entry by id :)**

If then, i do:

```
model.aggregate([ {
    $match : mongooseQuery // this is the query you see above
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            environments : '$environments'
        },
        avg : {
            '$avg' : '$price'
        }
    }
}]).exec(...)
```

i get the average price calculated as if the doc i explicitly excluded was in the results.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: To answer the question - you are providing too much irrelevant information and missing essential details. Please give an example of the document you are trying to exclude and explain how do you know the result is wrong.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you very much for trying to help, i found the problem and posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into the issue and found that it was not working because i was passing a string to $nin:

```
_id: { "$nin": [ "58be3e36309524218ca5eb2e" ] }
```

i changed it to:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var modelObjId = new ObjectID("58be3e36309524218ca5eb2e");

_id: { "$nin": [ modelObjId ] }
```

and this works good, the average is the correct one

hope it helps for anyone else running into this trouble

*do not hardcode strings, the code here is just an example :)*